# special data loading logic in ssis

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl

I have a dump file that i receive everyday and i wonder how to get it load through ssis and script task in sql server database. the format of the dump is mentioned below, from

These should be only two record rows, whereas in file i need to write a parser which can actually buffer the data and store in the column names A B C D .... AC. alphabets are column names and the data after = is the actual data that needs to be stored in those columns
Please i need help if anybody can help me loading this data.

```
<BEGIN
a=103216789021;
b=125230049;
c=TS1;
d=NON;
e=2;
d=TS1;
f=BC;
g=MIS;
H=100;
I=61005;
J=YES;
K=MC;
L=CW-ALL;
M=0;
N=CLIP;
O=ON;
P=1;
Q=90;
R=90;
S=90;
T=REE;
U=ALL;
V=0;
W=1382326697;
X=1382413166;
Y=01D81E170EE83C06;
Z=YES;
AB=NO;
AC=NO;
<END
<BEGIN
a=103216789021;
b=125230049;
c=TS1;
d=NON;
e=2;
d=TS1;
f=BC;
g=MIS;
H=100;
I=61005;
J=YES;
K=MC;
L=CW-ALL;
M=0;
N=CLIP;
O=ON;
P=1;
Q=90;
R=90;
S=90;
T=REE;
U=ALL;
V=0;
W=1382326697;
X=1382413166;
Y=01D81E170EE83C06;
Z=YES;
AB=NO;
AC=NO;
<END
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? A script task would easily be able to handle this for you.

Comment: I am not comfortable with programming, the problem is i want to write vb.net file parsing code but i cant make the logic of it. sorry i feel shame for this as i don't know. :(

Comment: No need to be ashamed. We all had to start somewhere :) Try and break things into manageable chunks. Your data actually looks pretty easy to work with. You always (seem to) have a predefined amount of columns, and their names are in the file. They are always followed by a '=' sign, and after the value, there's a nice semi-colon. 

Try and start by setting up an SSIS task with a data flow, and a script component (Transform) in it. Set it up to have 1 output column (A), and see if you can write the code to pull the value for 'A' out of the buffer input :)

Comment: ok let me try :) thanks anyways

Comment: PEOPLE! You don't have to code everything! This is just a completely normal delimited file except that the column delimiters are carriage returns and the row delimiter is `<END`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid good point!  ...but you do still have to split the column names from the values.  Which I suppose could be done in derived column expressions.

Comment: True. You could probably do that with a derived column, laborious as that would be..... also I'm not 100% sure on whether SSIS supports multi character row delimiters but its worth a try.

Comment: I never would have thought of it that way, but now I have a sweet new trick for my bag...thanks!!!

Comment: @alee Why there are two `d` values? Is that a typo? otherwise how you want to load it, does the `d` column gets loaded 4 times instead of 2?

Comment: d column is the actual repetition and not a typo. for that i think i need to make fields in table like d1 and d2 to map both columns differently. Any good ideas you throw?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way you could do this in a dataflow.   But it still requires some programming knowledge.

You would start by writing a script transformation that reads each row and updates a counter every time it hits a `<BEGIN` line.  It would otherwise not pass along the `<BEGIN` and `<END` rows.

Then it would split the incoming row on the = sign, and add the counter as a RowID column, so that the final output of the script transformation would look something like this:

```
RowId   ColumnName   Value
1       a            103216789021
1       b            125230049
...and so on...
1       ac           NO
2       a            103216789021
2       b            125230049
...and so on...
```

Then you use an UNPIVOT transformation to use the RowId for rows, the ColumnName for column names and the Value for the values.

Comment: thank u for reply, but there is repitition in the columns and even column count is not same. for one record may be the column count will be 10, for other may be it s 12.

Comment: You would have to handle this in the script transformation, changing the two d's to d1 & d2.  I'm not sure if UNPIVOT automatically handles missing columns.  If it doesn't, you would have to handle that in the script as well.